# Intent to create new Activity does not work with image files

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to create a new activity without images but when I use put an image on the new activity, the app always crashes when I try to create the new activity (pressing the button).

I have also added the second activity to the manifest file.

Here is the code:

activity_first.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".First" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:src="@drawable/desk" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/switchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="Switch!" />
```

First.Java

```
package com.example.multipleactivity;

public class First extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return true;
}
public void buttonClicked(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

activity_second.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/house" />
```

Second.java

```
  public class Second extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

the logCat on request:

```
 09-05 16:54:21.305: D/ActivityThread(19410): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-05 16:54:21.305: D/ActivityThread(19410): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-05 16:54:21.305: D/ActivityThread(19410): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
09-05 16:54:21.815: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19410): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-05 16:54:21.825: E/(19410): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-05 16:54:21.825: E/(19410): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-05 16:54:25.279: D/dalvikvm(19410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 519K, 28% free 15305K/21059K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
09-05 16:54:25.369: D/dalvikvm(19410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 22% free 20926K/26695K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
09-05 16:54:25.399: D/dalvikvm(19410): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 22% free 20917K/26695K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
09-05 16:54:25.399: E/dalvikvm-heap(19410): Out of memory on a 40960016-byte allocation.
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4164e6a0 self=0x4121fb10
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   | sysTid=19410 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074870352
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=28 stm=16 core=1
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:592)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-05 16:54:25.399: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at com.example.multipleactivity.Second.onCreate(Second.java:9)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-05 16:54:25.409: I/dalvikvm(19410):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 16:54:25.409: A/libc(19410): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 19410 (ultipleactivity)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: And the method which is called onButtonPressed `startActivity(Intent)`.

Comment: Well to create the new intent I used a method called "buttonClicked" which is in First.java.

Comment: The logcat output that you posted is incomplete. There's no information about the exception that was thrown.

Comment: Ok i added a new logcat. I copied the messages and pasted them. If this method doesn't get the whole output, please tell me how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`09-05 16:54:25.399: E/dalvikvm-heap(19410): Out of memory on a 40960016-byte allocation.`

You are running out of memory. Are your images really big?

Try to use smaller images by reducing the size or if you don't need them to be transparent, use `JPEG` instead of `PNG`.

Answer (score -1):

Please, can you copy/paste your entire xml files ?
For each XML Layout, you have to specify the main Layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc)

Example of layout for your activity 2 with a centered imageView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```